# React - Render components dinamically from json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to render components from a JSON like this:

```
const element = [
  {
    "component" : "container",
    "children" : [
      {
        "component" : "text",
        "content" : "foo"
      },
      {
        "component" : "text",
        "content" : "bar"
      },
    ] 
  }
]
```

The code is very simple, but I can't figure out why the container is being showed empty.

```
const allComponents = {
    text: (p) => {return <p>text</p>;},
    container: (p) => {return <div className='container'>{p.children}</div>;} 
};

function decoder(element) {
    const el = element.component;
    if (typeof allComponents[el] !== "undefined") {
        const Comp = allComponents[el];
        console.log('Decoding: ' + el);
      return (
        <Comp>
            {element.children && (
                element.children.map(child => {decoder(child)}) 
            )}
        </Comp>
      )
    }
  }
export default decoder;
```

The container is returned empty, and if I log `p.children` the output is an array of undefined objects. Any idea ?

Comment: how are you using your decoder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `decoder` must be used like a `react component`, so:

- It should start with a `capital case`, ie: `Decoder`.
- It should always `return something`: add `return null` like an else to the check on undefined.
- When `mapping on children`, you `must return something` (you are actually just executing decoder function and not returning).

Summarizing:

```
function Decoder({ element }) {
  const el = element.component;
  if (typeof allComponents[el] !== "undefined") {
    const Comp = allComponents[el];
    console.log("Decoding: " + el);
    return (
      <Comp>
        {element.children &&
          element.children.map(child => <Decoder element={child} />)}
      </Comp>
    );
  }
  return null;
}
```

PS: you need a key for the inner Decoder

Here is a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-forest-s7e5j)

**edit**

To show your text content, you need that the text component supports it, and then you will pass it as a prop to the Comp rendering, like illustrated in the sandbox.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'm learning React and really didn't know how to solve this. Thank for your answer ;)